# Run Ubuntu Linux on a MacBook Pro

Tags: ubuntu, mac, macbook, bootloader

I'm trying to run Ubuntu Linux on my Mac but it doesn't work.  When the system starts, a black screen appears with the message "*Unable to find a medium containing a live file system*."

I also tried downloading the Ubuntu and Kubuntu ISO images several times, but the same message appears when I boot from them.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special version available for Macbook users, did you use that iso?

When you download the .iso file make sure that it contains "+mac" in the filename.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download

- Scroll down to DVD downloads
- Select your closest country
- Find the right directory  ".../11.10/release/"
- Scroll down until you find the right file. Example: ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso

Also, check out this link for more help on installing Ubuntu on Apple hardware: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro